# UISearchBar presented by UISearchController in table header view animates too far when active

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am using UISearchController to present a search bar inside the header view of a tableview:

```
...
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;            
self.presentingTVC.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.presentingTVC.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

(where setting the tableHeaderView property twice is necessary as otherwise the header view overlaps the first row, c.f.[a couple of answers on S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5764819/2199136) )

This is how it looks, perfectly in position when inactive: 
[image: Inactive search bar in correct position]

The search bar should just stay in place when active - I don't want it to move up to hide the navigation bar. But it unexpectedly animates down, leaving a blank space between it and the navigation bar:

[image: Screenshot showing search bar animated too far down]

Here's a
[video of weird search bar animation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/inavj9qthorpd8k/searchbaranimation2.mov?dl=0)

If I just use a search bar separately from UISearchController, it does not show the same behaviour when it becomes active.

In my presenting view controller, I have `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;` and `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;`, and in IB none of the "extend edges" boxes are active (all seemed to be possible things that could throw search presentation off, from reading around).

Does anyone know how I can stop the search bar from animating down?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I tried going through Apple's sample project here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html but still no luck. Will update if I find an answer.

Comment: None of the solution worked for me: (

Comment: Your video link is now broken.

Comment: Should be fixed now :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok so I finally figured out a solution for myself. Though it's more than likely we have other things in our code / storyboard (that's why this is a hard question to answer), for the most part I followed Apple's tutorial on UISearchController: (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html)

Just about all my code is identical to theirs, but I couldn't get the search bar to not jump when clicking inside of it. So what I did was check "under opaque bars" for both the original table view and the search results table view in my storyboard. That got the search bar to stop jumping.

But there was one last issue, which was the fact that the first row of the results table view was hidden by the search bar. In order to fix that I added `self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(kHeightOfTableViewCells, 0, 0, 0);` to the `viewDidLoad` method of my results table view. Voila!

Comment: It should be noted here that 'kHeightOfTableViewCells' is a constant I set in my table view class to define how tall my cells are.

Comment: Yep I think that's getting somewhere! - see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/19585104/2199136

Comment: Under opaque bars on the view controller in the storyboard did it for me, thanks!

Comment: I had set my navigation bar as opaque recently and this got the bar jumping, what a crazy behavior!

Comment: Thanks! It helped. I wonder how did you get to that solution? 
Oh, how I love strange jumps or gaps in TableView which can be prevented by obscure boolean flags...

Comment: To be honest I just experimented with every option I could think of and that one finally worked. This one was a bit of a head scratcher at the time.

Answer (score 68):

Old question but I was able to solve this issue by setting

`self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;`

on my view controller. I think is issue is caused by having an opaque navigation bar but setting `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` to `NO` on your search controller, causing the search bar to incorrectly position itself when focused.

Comment: `public var extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars: Bool // Defaults to NO, but bars are translucent by default on 7_0.`

So I really think Apple should by default set it to YES, since iOS7

Comment: This works. Looks like the other solutions are a workaround.

Comment: The combination of: `self.definesPresentationContext = YES; ` and  `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES; ` works for me.

Comment: Garanda's solution works for me too, the difference is I added this 2 in storyboard when read storyboard in xml.  <viewController storyboardIdentifier="xxxVC" extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars="YES" definesPresentationContext="YES" id="hgJ-Px-OtG" userLabel="xxxxViewController" customClass="xxxxViewController" .....

Answer (score 28):

I was able to prevent `UISearchBar` from shifting down by removing the following line from my ViewController:
`self.definesPresentationContext = YES;`

Comment: Fabulous answer. The idea is to make root view controller as the presenter of the search controller when there's multiple container VCs in the mix. By not setting, we are falling back to the root view controller resolved the insidious issues emanating from detached parent view controller(s). Thank you!

Comment: At first it worked. But later I noticed that I had a crash because of this fix: if I search and there are no results, tapping the button in the placeholder caused "no selector" type of crash - the button's segue wasn't working. Probably specifics of my setup, but be careful. The combination of `self.definesPresentationContext = true` and `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true` worked better for my setup.

Answer (score 23):

**definesPresentationContext = true**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Prominent
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        definesPresentationContext = true
```

Comment: Me toooooo ! the ```definesPresentationContext = true``` is the life !

Comment: Worked for me! On other segue the controller was presenting fine, but on another stack it was disappearing. This fixed the issue on both.

Answer (score 16):

My turn. I also had this problem when I followed the WWDC sample code.

I noticed that if I didn't set the scopeButtonTitles property of the searchBar, the searchBar would not be visible. Upon closer inspection, it just had a frame of CGRectZero. This means that setting the scopeButtonTitles sets the frame behind the scenes. So If don't want to show any scopeButtonTitles, but still want to not have to hardcode UISearchBar to a specific height, set the scopeButtonTitles to an empty array.

```
self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = []
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
```

Setting the scopeButtonTitles to an array of 1 strings will not display the scope button titles, but still have logic to deal with the view, essentially screwing up the layout.

Props to Apple's QA team (applicable to iOS 8)

Comment: Totally awesome. Works for my tableview with custom row layout on iOS 8!

Comment: Setting an empty array for the scope definitely solves this problem on iOS8 when you're using a custom view controller and your own table / collection view.

Comment: You can also call `sizeToFit` to fix the zero-size problem.

Answer (score 15):

I ran to this problem just recently and none of the solutions worked for me. Maybe because my UI is more complex (My table view with search supports in contained in UITabController inside a UiNavigationController) anyway, none of the above worker.
I could simply solve my problem by this very neat piece of code I found at:
[UISearchController Not Redisplaying Navigation Bar on Rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552967/uisearchcontroller-not-redisplaying-navigation-bar-on-rotate)

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar
{
    if (bar == searchController.searchBar) {
        return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
    }
    else { // Handle other cases
        return UIBarPositionAny;
    }
}
```

**One more thing to add:** after setting all my controller's hierarchy to extend under opaque and top bars, my search bar started to appear hidden under navigation bar and would've appeared right just after a rotation might happened. that was a cue for me that there is some lay out error and some information abut my layout was not right. this delegate method helps my controller understand the situation about the otherwise nomad search bar!

Answer (score 6):

Found it! This seems to be the offensive line in `viewDidLoad` of the presenting vc:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Removed that and the search bar stayed in place as predicted.

Comment: This didn't do it for me as I don't have this code in my project. I tried using another sample project: https://github.com/dempseyatgithub/Sample-UISearchController and breaking it down piece by piece but still no luck. Will keep searching.

Comment: Hmm annoying! You can set the edgesForExtendedLayout on the view controller in the storyboard as well with the Extend Edges checkboxes. Maybe double check those?

Comment: Also - I'm running into weird animations from the fact that UISearchController is now a fully fledged presented VC - so for example, I was seeing a weird dismissal animation where the search bar would fall to the bottom of the VC when Cancel was clicked. That was due to the presenting VC providing a transition context with a Vertical Transition type selected. All to say that perhaps if I understood a bit better how the presentation mechanisms are working, I might be able to debug all this weirdness more easily...!

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I'm messing around with the view controller check boxes on the storyboard. I fixed the scroll view jumping by checking "Under Opaque Bars" but now the first row of the table in the search controller is hidden by the search bar. Getting close ....

Answer (score 4):

unchecking **Adjust Scroll View Insets**

and

checking **Under Top Bars**

**Fixed** my problem[image]

Comment: thanks man! after lots of digging, this is the only solution that worked for me . cheers!! you saved my day

Answer (score 3):

for iOS 11 & swift 4, set the line bellow in the viewController resolved my issue (searchBar jump down):

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .bottom
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you set UISearchBar `frame.original.y = 64`

there are the code

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) {
    [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
}

searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 376, 44);
```

wash can help you

Answer (score 1):

If you use `UINavigationController` and `TabBar` you *can't* use:

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

You would need this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46151063/3369381

Answer (score 1):

Mine was the order of elements on the main controller .xib file.

This worked.

[image: This worked]

This didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting the nav bar to `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` fixed the problem.  It seems that the search bar presentation layer doesn't take into account the translucence of the nav bar when laying out the search bar.

I realize this isn't a perfect solution, because the translucence of the nav bar can throw off layout elsewhere, but it at least fixes the problem in the case where a non-translucent nav bar is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the first post everyone needed a different solution. So here is mine. I had to combine two things mentioned on this page, namely:

Swift 2:

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true

    edgesForExtendedLayout = .None
```

Answer (score 0):

its very simple just do clipsToBounds = true of header view of table view in witch search bar is added.

```
countryTableView.tableHeaderView?.clipsToBounds = true
```