# Search Bar is changing position when clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have written code for searchBar in Objective C for iOS devices and it is working fine on iPhone but when it comes to iPad it is changing its x value and due to which cancel button is also hiding.

Initially Search bar looks like:

[image]

After Clicking in search bar:

[image]

Does anybody face this issue and suggest me something in this ?

Here is the code:

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];    
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
followTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
UISearchBar.appearance.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; //Cancel button color

[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];

tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]init];
[tapGesture addTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureBtnAction:)];

self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = searchBarColor;


-(IBAction)tapGestureBtnAction:(id)sender
{
  [_searchController.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

  [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show code of "tapGestureBtnAction"

Comment: Updated. Please check

Comment: Please post full code for this. Then we will get something.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened to me as well,
Just set this to NO.

```
self.definesPresentationContext = NO
```

check this: [UISearchController Search Bar Position Drops 64 points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093042/uisearchcontroller-search-bar-position-drops-64-points)

Comment: Yes, I found that. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for participation.

By setting, self.definesPresentationContext = NO; The issue is resolved. I found this solution by following this: [UISearchController Search Bar Position Drops 64 points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093042/uisearchcontroller-search-bar-position-drops-64-points)

Answer (score 0):

for swift 4.x, this worked for me

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your UISearchController in **viewWillAppear** function.