# Scope buttons hiding behind the UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchcontroller, iphone-8-plus

I am creating a search screen using UISearchController, in which I have to show three scope buttons.I have put search bar programmatically.But somehow the scope buttons are hiding behind the UITableView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.tblFoundList.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]}];
    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setAttributedPlaceholder:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Search by" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor]}]];
    self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
    self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"A",@"B", @"C"];
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
}
```

[image: Scope buttons hiding behind the UITableview]

Could anyone help in this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: @iPeter I have put it programmatically, no auto layout.

Comment: Then please check the frame of your `tableview` and the `buttons`. As per the screenshot it seems like the `y position` of your `tableview` is incorrect.

Comment: try giving height of tableHeaderView, in which OS u are checking this ? iOS11 provides default header height which may cause this issue. changing table header height should work.

Comment: @iPeter, I tried changing the y position of the TableView created by me, yet it showed no results. But thank you for help

Comment: @torap I tried increasing the height of the header height too but even that didn't seem to work. Thanks for help

Comment: Can you show your `storyboard`? @SimerynDenis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned earlier I had created UISearchController programmatically, so the UITableview in the image is UISearchController's UITableview, that is why nothing was affecting it.

So I got help from

[UISearchController Search Bar Position Drops 64 points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093042/uisearchcontroller-search-bar-position-drops-64-points)

and

[UISearchBar presented by UISearchController in table header view animates too far when active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326269/uisearchbar-presented-by-uisearchcontroller-in-table-header-view-animates-too-fa/30010473#30010473)

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar
    {
      if (bar == self.searchController.searchBar) {
        return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
      }
      else { // Handle other cases
        return UIBarPositionAny;
      }
    }
```

On adding following method the search bar got shifted up and the scope buttons were visible.

But thank you all for helping out.