# Unable to select search result in UISearchController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller

I have a `tableView` list in my IOS app. I wish to search my `tableView` list with `UISearchController`. By default the list will display correctly.

When I active search controller (Click on the `UISearchController`), my existing list will disappear and when I key in related keywords, result will be displayed accordingly.

But when I check on related search result, `searchController` will be deactivate and back to default list.

Any idea?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;

    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

    self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = ThemeLightGrayColor;

    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

    [self.searchController.searchBar.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:229.0/255 green:229.0/255 blue:229.0/255 alpha:1].CGColor];
    [self.searchController.searchBar setPlaceholder:@"Search"];
    [self.searchController.searchBar.layer setBorderWidth:0.5];
    [self.searchController.searchBar setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter" size:14]}];

    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];


    _searchResultArr=[NSMutableArray array];
    _tableView.tableHeaderView = ({
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, DCNaviH, 0, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height + 50);
        _segPromotion = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"All",@"Near Me",@"Coming Soon"]];
        _segPromotion.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
        _segPromotion.backgroundColor = ThemeWhiteColor;
        _segPromotion.frame = CGRectMake(10, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y+5 + self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height , ScreenW-20, 30);
        [_segPromotion setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName :  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter" size:13],NSForegroundColorAttributeName: ThemeDarkBlueColor } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_segPromotion setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter" size:13],NSForegroundColorAttributeName : ThemeWhiteColor} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [_segPromotion addTarget:self action:@selector(SegmentChangeViewValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        [view addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
        [view addSubview:_segPromotion];
        view;
    });
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
}


- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    NSString *searchString = searchController.searchBar.text;
    [self searchForText:searchString];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}



- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self updateSearchResultsForSearchController:self.searchController];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:(NSInteger)selectedScope
{
    [self updateSearchResultsForSearchController:self.searchController];
}


- (void)searchForText:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[self.searchBar scopeButtonTitles][self.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]];
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear... What does `searchForText` do ? What happens when you select a search result ?

Comment: Hi AnthoPak, updated with searchForText function. When I tried to click on search result, cancel button in UISearchController will disappear and the list will reset back to default listing.

Comment: Hum... Maybe you can try to add `self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;`

Comment: Hi AnthoPak, thanks alot, its works!!! but the UISearchController bar will remain after I click on search result (Expected result: after click on selected result will push to another ViewController page). How can I hide it after click in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I found this post and it help me to solve the issue as mentioned above. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093042/uisearchcontroller-search-bar-position-drops-64-points

Comment: Sorry i've just seen your comments ! Glad to know you've solve your issue. Will add this as an answer as it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is adding `self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;` when initializing the searchController.

This is because, as you have used `[[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil]`, the results will be shown in the same view controller (because of `nil` parameter). For this reason, if `obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation` is set to `YES` (this is the case by default), the results area won't be touchable.