# Why is my UISearchController not rendering correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to create a `UINavigationController` with a `UISearchController` similar to the one in this screenshot.

[image]

However, it ends up being rendered like the following screenshot:

[image]

I am not sure why the gap is being rendered.

I have the following code to set up the `UISearchController`:

```
func configureSearchController() {
    let searchController = UISearchController()
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for a username"
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
}
```

Comment: This could be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093042/uisearchcontroller-search-bar-position-drops-64-points

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is that you have nested NavigationViewControllers. You're probably wrapping the tab bar in a navigation controller, and then each tab as well. Remove the outer one and you should be fine.

In summary it should go:

1. root view = UITabBarController()
2. Each tab of UITabBarController() is wrapped in a UINavigationController()
3. Inside each UINavigationController() is the actual view you want to show (InstaKidsVC in your case)