# UISearchController - blank space hides status bar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, statusbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm using a UISearchController and it is working fine. However it is leaving a blank space over the search bar (when it is focused) which partially hides the status bar. [This espace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WczDA.png)

I already tried setting the `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone` also `self.navigationController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES` but the space is still there. I tried setting the  `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;`but it generated that the searchBar take the status bar position [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bFt0.png).

I'm using a `UIViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`. This is the setUp that im implementing now:

```
@interface DirectoryViewController :  UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate ,UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *personsArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults;


@implementation DirectoryViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
UINavigationController *searchResultsController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableSearchResultsNavController"];

    // Our instance of UISearchController will use searchResults
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];

    // The searchcontroller's searchResultsUpdater property will contain our tableView.
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

    //Cancel button tint
    _searchController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.searchController.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar"]
                                                forBarPosition:0
                                                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) { /// iOS 7 or above
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    }

    self.navigationController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;

}
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28373171/2597566).

Changing the tableInsets:

```
    self.directoryTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10, 0, 0, 0);
```

when the searchController is becameFirstResponder

and

```
    self.directoryTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

when the search bar action is finished.