# How to dismiss slide down search bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I've a search bar. When I clicked on the text field the search bar slide down on 40pt average.

How I can dismiss it?

I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326269/uisearchbar-presented-by-uisearchcontroller-in-table-header-view-animates-too-fa) answer, and tried to implement those tip, but unfortunately it's doesn't work for me. However this line: `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true` partially help me. But through time when I clicked on the text field the search bar is disappears(

Have you any idea to sort out this issue?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your result in simulator and the code it relates to?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set,

```
   self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

in your `viewdidload`.

**Update :**

try

```
  self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
  self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

or only

```
 self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

Comment: Can you give more tip?

Comment: where you puttin searchbar? in tableviewcontroller? and it is searchbar controller or normal searchbar? i need to your setup to exactly identify issue!!

Comment: Sorry for my late reply... Yes, I'm putting SearchBarController in TableViewController on ViewDidLoad method. I think maybe I should use just SearchBar instead of SearchBarController?