# Odd UISearchController behavior on table view header

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchresultscontroller

This is something I've done before that has worked perfectly, so I'm puzzled as to why it's not functioning correctly now.

What I'm wanting to do is have a search bar in the header of my table view that doesn't move when it becomes active. I've achieved this in another view using the same `tableView.tableHeaderView` method (the one difference between the two is that the working `searchController` is in a `TableViewController` embedded in a `NavigationController` instead of in a regular `ViewController` with a table).

I'll get to the code momentarily, here are the pictures.

Incorrect behavior: BEFORE SEARCH

[image: Before entering search criteria]

AFTER SEARCH

[image: After entering search criteria]

As you can see, in the second image, when the `searchController` becomes active, it jumps up to the top of the view instead of staying in the `headerView` like I think it should. It also leaves a really ugly gap at the top of the `tableView` where the header is. I made a prior version of my app about a year ago where the search functionality on this screen worked perfectly, and using the same exact code from that project still results in this weird behavior where the `searchController` leaves the `tableView`.

In terms of my code, I've made my class conform to `UISearchResultsUpdating` and have implemented the required `updateSearchResults(for:)` function.

I declared my variable in my class:

```
var searchController: UISearchController!
```

And then in my `viewDidLoad`, I do the following:

```
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = .white
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = GlobalPropertyKeys.LovalyticsBlue
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    allListItemsTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Which is the same code that works in my other `viewController` (granted, the other one *is* a `tableViewController`, but I had also made an `@IBOutlet` for the `tableView` there and attached the `searchController` to the `tableHeaderView`). It's probably worth mentioning that those radio buttons at the top trigger my `tableView` to display different arrays. In the old version of my app, it was really cool because toggling those radio buttons while the `searchController` was active would display the search results for each array automatically.

Am I missing something incredibly obvious here?

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326269/uisearchbar-presented-by-uisearchcontroller-in-table-header-view-animates-too-fa?

Comment: @crizzis Wow looks like this is a problem that's been plaguing some people for a while, thanks for the link. I went through every answer to see if it solved my issue, but no dice unfortunately. I tried checking Under Opaque Bars in my view controller, setting extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars to true, definesPresentationContext = true, searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [], edgesForExtendedLayout = .none, checking Under Top Bars in my view controller, setting the navigation bar to translucent, setting clipsToBounds = true, and edgesForExtendedLayout = .bottom and pretty much every combination.